# Python NLTK named entities

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to NLTK. I have a text file which contains text about medicines and their side effects. so I need to extract the medicine name and the names of side effects.

towards this I have written this code

```
import sys, re, nltk, pprint
x = "Allegra (fexofenadine hydrochloride) is an antihistamine used to 
     treat allergic symptoms of seasonal allergic rhinitis (sneezing, 
     runny nose, itchy or watery eyes), and urticaria (hives). Allegra is 
     available as a generic drug termed fexofenadine hydrochloride. 
     Allegra is used in adults and children (2 years and older for 
     allergies, 6 months and older for hives) for the control and 
     reduction of the above symptoms. Some common side effects of Allegra
     include GI symptoms of nausea or diarrhea, muscle or back discomfort
     or pain, sleepiness, and menstrual cramps."
data = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(data)
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)
```

I get a very complex output

```
Tree('S', [Tree('NE', [('Allegra', 'NNP')]), ('(', ':'), 
    ('fexofenadine', 'NN'), ('hydrochloride', 'NN'), (')', ':'), 
    ('is', 'VBZ'), ('an', 'DT'), ('antihistamine', 'NN'), 
    ('used', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('treat', 'VB'), ('allergic', 'JJ'), 
    ('symptoms', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('seasonal', 'JJ'), 
    ('allergic', 'NN'), ('rhinitis', 'NNS'), ('(', ':'), 
    ('sneezing', 'VBG'), (',', ','), ('runny', 'JJ'), ('nose', 'NN'), 
    (',', ','), ('itchy', 'JJ'), ('or', 'CC'), ('watery', 'NN'), 
    ('eyes', 'NNS'), (')', ':'), (',', ','), ('and', 'CC'), 
    ('urticaria', 'VB'), ('(', ':'), ('hives', 'NNS'), (')', 'VBP'),
    ('.', '.'), ('Allegra', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('available', 'JJ'), 
    ('as', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('generic', 'JJ'), ('drug', 'NN'), 
    ('termed', 'VBD'), ('fexofenadine', 'NN'), ('hydrochloride', 'NN'), 
    ('.', '.'), ('Allegra', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('used', 'VBN'), 
    ('in', 'IN'), ('adults', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('children', 'NNS'), 
    ('(', ':'), ('2', 'CD'), ('years', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), 
    ('older', 'JJR'), ('for', 'IN'), ('allergies', 'NNS'), (',', ','), 
    ('6', 'CD'), ('months', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('older', 'JJR'), 
    ('for', 'IN'), ('hives', 'NNS'), (')', ':'), ('for', 'IN'), 
    ('the', 'DT'), ('control', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('reduction', 'NN'), 
    ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('above', 'JJ'), ('symptoms', 'NNS'), 
    ('.', '.'), ('Some', 'DT'), ('common', 'JJ'), ('side', 'NN'), 
    ('effects', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('Allegra', 'NNP'), 
    ('include', 'VBP'), ('GI', 'NNP'), ('symptoms', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), 
    ('nausea', 'NN'), ('or', 'CC'), ('diarrhea', 'NN'), (',', ','), 
    ('muscle', 'NN'), ('or', 'CC'), ('back', 'RB'), ('discomfort', 'JJ'), 
    ('or', 'CC'), ('pain', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('sleepiness', 'NN'), 
    (',', ','), ('and', 'CC'), ('menstrual', 'JJ'), ('cramps', 'NNS'), 
    ('.', '.')])
```

Now this is really confusing because what I was hoping to get was

1. Allegra
2. nausea
3. diarrhea,
4. Muscle or back discomfort or pain,
5. sleepiness,
6. menstrual cramps

So how do I narrow down to the data which I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're asking two questions here. First, NLTK gives you a tree, but you're only interested in the named entities. You can select them like this:

```
for subtree in t.subtrees(filter=lambda x: x.label() == 'NE'):
    print subtree.leaves()
```

Second, however, this output shows you that Python has only identified one of the answers you're looking for as a named entity. This means you'll have to find other ways than the standard ne_chunk to get your answers. There are a number of options here. For example, you could train a new named entity tagger on your own data, where all appropriate words are labelled as named entities. If you don't have any labelled data, you could use a resource like [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to look up the semantic type of each word or phrase, and only keep those words that fall under "symptom", for example. Alternatively, you could use semantic vectors (such as the ones produced by Google's [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)) to identify all words in your sentence that are sufficiently similar to a reference word such as "illness".

Comment: The symptoms are not "named entities" by the commonly accepted definition. Manually extracting a bunch of them and then training a new classifier is unlikely to work because it doesn't distinguish between symptoms that the medicine should cure, and symptoms which may be induced as side effects. You need a more sophisticated parser to make this distinction. In the general case, this is beyond the current state of the art, but for a very constrained scenario like this you can probably hack something up which achieves acceptable precision.

Comment: Upvote for a promising attempt, even though I think it may be incomplete, as outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

As a somewhat ad hoc solution outline, I would suggest adding [noun phrase extraction](http://www.monlp.com/2012/01/20/extracting-noun-phrases-from-parsed-trees/) and a simple heuristic to only extract symptom candidates starting from the first sentence which contains "side effects" (or perhaps a small set of near-synonyms).  This is rooted in the observation that pharmaceutical declarations tend to have a rather rigid structure, where the drug's intended use is described first, then its possible side effects and other caveats.

From the symptom candidates, you can probably keep a catalog of common symptoms, then assume anything sandwiched between two known symptoms is also a symptom, as they tend to be just a list of comma-separated noun phrases, possibly with conjunctions between some of them.

Comment: Did you make any further progress on this? Also, could we say what you are looking for is possibly concept extraction - like if someone looks for "muscle or back discomfort or pain", they get "Allegra" as one of the possible answers.